# Code runs perfect in g++ but not in Xcode - Cannot find File

Tags: c++, xcode, g++

I have created a text file with content. It is located in the same folder as the cpp files. And I have confirmed several times that the file exists. When I run g++, compile and run it finds the file. When I run it in Xcode, it does not work. If fails to find the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
      getline (myfile,line);
      cout << line << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make sure the working directory settings in the Xcode project is set to where you have the file you're looking for.

Comment: See [this question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769314/how-to-reference-files-relatively-in-xcode-4-c).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your file fails to open because XCode launches from the IDE in the default *build* location, which is actually a temporary directory off somewhere on your disk. If you want change the working directory at launch-time to something else (like the location where your files can be found):

1. Select the Product/Edit Scheme... menu option.
2. Select the **Run** schema in the left list.
3. At the bottom  **Options** tab on the right pane should be a "Working Directory" option. Check the checkbox and set the custom working directory to someplace you *know* (your "/Users/yourname" home directory is a decent place that I use).
4. Make sure any "current directory" data files you need for your program execution from the IDE are in this directory.

And in case you didn't see it, this is also the place where you can configure command-line arguments (on another tab) of the same dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add files to the project in XCode or use the absolute path instead.

Comment: Thanks for trying but we are not answered yet. I added the file to project directly from XCode, just to be certain. Don't you find it odd that when I compile it at the terminal it works perfectly, and when I run it in XCode nothing? Why would the absolute path be needed for XCode and not g++?