# How to access files in iOS project inside C++ function?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, swift, opencv

So I call my C++ function through my `OpenCVWrapper`. In this function I have to open a file which is located in my Xcode project. Is it possible to specify the desired path in C++ function? 
Or I have to pass a file through the `OpenCVWrapper` in Swift?

In short, it looks smth like:

```
func sample() {
    OpenCVWrapper.booProcess()
}
```

in `OpenCVWrapper.mm`

```
@implementation OpenCVWrapper : NSObject

+ (void)booProcess {
    boo();
}

- (void)boo:
{
    return boo();
}

@end
```

blink.cpp

```
void boo()
{
    cv::CascadeClassifier my_cascade;
    my_cascade.load("bar.xml");
}
```

All necessary wrappers have been added.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU92u.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't find any proper way to get a file path in C++ function. So the most obvious solution is getting a String representation of the path in Swift.

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("bar", ofType:"xml")
```

Then pass it through the wrapper to C++ function

```
OpenCVWrapper.booProcess(path)
```

In your OpenCVWrapper.mm you have to convert a `NSString` into a `std::string` like

```
std::string *mypath = new std::string([path UTF8String]);
```

Then you may pass this path to C++ function through the wrapper.

```
+ (void)booProcess:(NSString*)path {
    std::string *mypath = new std::string([path UTF8String]);
    boo(*mypath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not currently possible to call C++ code from Swift. You will have to wrap `OpenCVWrapper` in Objective-C, and then call it in Swift.

See [Using Swift with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35) for more info.

Comment: Eh? I've made all necessary wrappers for C++ code.. The question is not about directly using C++ from swift. It's about 'how to access files in iOS project inside C++ function?'

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438393/new-to-xcode-cant-open-files-in-c
If this is it, I'll just change my answer to link to it and give a brief synopsis.

Comment: Actually, there is a sense to check, but I am not sure that opening file in command line-like project is equivalent to the opening file in iOS.

Comment: I've watched. It has nothing common with my issue.